# Android Firestore unit tests produce Looper error

Tags: android, firebase, junit

I'm trying to unit test some Firestore functionality like so:

```
@Test
public void ratingTest() throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    FirebaseUtils.doTask(1, new FirebaseUtils.OnComplete() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            //assertions
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail() {
            //assertions
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    latch.await();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$UiExecutor.<clinit>(FirebaseApp.java:696)
```

I've already found a supposed solution, which involves adding the following the the test class:

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

And this to the gradle:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

This does not seem to make a difference and I can't find any other solutions.